# Postgresql upgrade issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, upgrade, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to test the Postgresql 9.3 -> 9.4 upgrade process on the development environment on windows and I get weird issue during the pg_upgrade invocation:

```
PS D:\bin\postgres-9.4> .\bin\pg_upgrade.exe -b ..\postgres-9.3\bin\ -B .\bin -d ..\postgres-9.3\data -D .\data -c -v -U postgres
Running in verbose mode
Running in verbose mode
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
pg_control values:

First log segment after reset:        000000010000000000000061
pg_control version number:            937
Catalog version number:               201306121
Database system identifier:           6153485438384190463
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/1920
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          19276
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        667
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by reference
Data page checksum version:           0
Current pg_control values:

pg_control version number:            942
Catalog version number:               201409291
Database system identifier:           6155476934462898984
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/677
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          12136
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        667
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Size of a large-object chunk:         2048
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by reference
Data page checksum version:           0


Values to be changed:

First log segment after reset:        000000010000000000000002
"..\postgres-9.3\bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "..\postgres-9.3\data" -o "-p 50432 -b " start >> "pg_upgrade_server_start.log" 2>&1
executing: SELECT datcollate, datctype FROM     pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE    datname = 'template0'
executing: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE    datname = 'template0'
executing: SELECT c.relname, c.relfilenode FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c,          pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND              n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' AND            c.relname = 'pg_database' ORDER BY c.relname
executing: SELECT d.oid, d.datname, pg_catalog.pg_tablespace_location(t.oid) AS spclocation FROM pg_catalog.pg_databased  LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace t  ON d.dattablespace = t.oid WHERE d.datallowconn = true ORDER BY 2
executing: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE info_rels (reloid) AS SELECT c.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n     ON c.relnamespace = n.oid LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i         ON c.oid = i.indexrelid WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'm', 'i', 'S') AND  i.indisvalid IS DISTINCT FROM false AND  i.indisready IS DISTINCT FROM false AND   ((n.nspname !~ '^pg_temp_' AND     n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast_temp_' AND     n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'binary_upgrade', 'pg_toast') AND         c.oid >= 16384)   OR (n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' AND     relname IN ('pg_largeobject', 'pg_largeobject_loid_pn_index', 'pg_largeobject_metadata', 'pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index') ));
SQL command failed
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE info_rels (reloid) AS SELECT c.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i         ON c.oid = i.indexrelid WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'm', 'i', 'S') AND  i.indisvalid IS DISTINCT FROM false AND  i.indisready IS DISTINCT FROM false AND   ((n.nspname !~'^pg_temp_' AND     n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast_temp_' AND     n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema',                                        'binary_upgrade', 'pg_toast') AND         c.oid >= 16384)   OR (n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' AND     relname IN ('pg_largeobject', 'pg_largeobject_loid_pn_index', 'pg_largeobject_metadata', 'pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index') ));
ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 25370

Failure, exiting
"..\postgres-9.3\bin/pg_ctl" -w -D "..\postgres-9.3\data" -o "" -m fast stop >> "pg_upgrade_utility.log" 2>&1
```

Both clusters (old and new one were shut down properly and I can start them without any issues in logs. If I do backup/restore of the databases into a new postgresql 9.3 cluster the process finishes successfully, but it is a bad solution if it would happen on the production environment. What could be the problem and what should I do to prevent this issue from happening again?

Thanks!

Small update: there're no records with OID 25370 in any system tables and no files/folder in the cluster directory with this name.

Comment: Did you disable (or even un-installed) your anti-virus program? These kind of problems often arise because the anti-virus blocks access to the files. If you can't disable the anti-virus, at least exclude the data directories from scanning.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your suggestion, but I tried this procedure with the same set of files on two different machines, the second one had no antivirus except windows defender, and I got the same result after I disabled windows defender-related services and real-time protection.